# Rotas Filhas no Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tenho uma rota filha que abre um componente, o componente não é carregado, mas a url sim o que pode ser?

App Routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'
import { EventosComponent } from './eventos/eventos.component';
import { MeusDadosComponent } from './meus-dados/meus-dados.component';
import { NovoeventoComponent } from './eventos/novoevento/novoevento.component';
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
{path: '', component: HomeComponent},
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path: 'eventos', component: EventosComponent,
     children: [
         {path: 'novoevento', component: NovoeventoComponent},
     ]},
{path:'meus-dados', component: MeusDadosComponent }
]
```

Marcação que chama o componente:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['novoevento']"> 
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info round button-full-width" style="margin-right: 20px !important">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus "></span> Novo Evento</button>
                    </a>
```

No console não mostra mais nenhum erro

Comment: Aparentemente esse erro não se trata da rotas, mas sim do import do Observable, da uma olhada [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464852/rxjs-observable-throw-is-not-a-function-angular4)

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o routerLink dessa forma? `<a routerLink="novoevento">`

Comment: Tentei, mesma coisa :/

Comment: @LucasVellido, acho que realmente o problema é no Observable, ele ta passando como null, mas o código está certo :/ eu acho rsrs

Comment: Qual a versão do rxjs você está usando? Em vez de `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'` tenta fazer `import { throwError } from 'rxjs'` e no código usar `return throwError(errorMessage)`

Comment: @LeonardoLima, obrigado, resolveu a parte do Observable, mas infelizmente o componente ainda não está sendo carregado, achei estranho que ele da um connection refused na porta 3000, mas nem tô mexendo nessa porta.

Comment: Entendi qual era o erro, ao fazer o load do componente de eventos, ele da um get pra um json server, e esse json server estava offline, agora eu subi ele e o erro sumiu, mas o problema de não exibir o componente NOVOEVENTO, continua.

Comment: Não seria `<a [routerLink]="['eventos/novoevento']"> `?

Comment: Tente importar o `RouterModule` do `@angular/router` e coloque `RouterModule.forRoot()` no seu import do `AppComponent`. Pelas importações, esse modulo não está  sendo importado.

Comment: Você pode compartilhar o seu EventosComponent e o modulo onde você declara eles?